# MySQL Downgrading Composite Primary Key to be more restrictive

Tags: mysql, database, primary-key, database-migration, composite-primary-key

I've got the following table used to track users who are watching a support ticket

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS crm_ticketwatcher (
  ticketid int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  employeeid int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  contactid int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (ticketid,employeeid,contactid)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

I want to have a downgrade script that removes contactid from the primary key.

The table content looks a bit like this

```
ticketid|employeeid|contactid
--------|----------|---------
5       |5         |0
5       |8         |0
5       |0         |2
5       |0         |3
```

When I run my (unsuccessful) downgrade script,

`ALTER TABLE crm_ticketwatcher DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY (ticketid, employeeid);`

I get the following error:

`ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 1: Duplicate entry '306-0' for key 'PRIMARY'`

because there are now 2 rows with the primary key set (5, 0)

What's the best way to drop the additional rows from the table, saving the last occurring one?

We're on MySQL 5.7.13, so the IGNORE keyword is not an option.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you also tell me the structure of the table that you'll get "last occurring" information? like date. Or you just want to keep highest or lowest contactid row? Which one you're keeping (5, 0, 2) or (5, 0, 3)?

Comment: (5, 0, 3) would be kept because it's the lowest row

Comment: I think eggyal's answer should work for this case.

Comment: it works for this case because 3 happens to be larger than 2, but in the full table the lowest row's contactid does not show this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As documented under [ALTER TABLE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/alter-table.html):

> `IGNORE` is a MySQL extension to standard SQL. It controls how [`ALTER TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/alter-table.html) works if there are duplicates on unique keys in the new table or if warnings occur when strict mode is enabled. If `IGNORE` is not specified, the copy is aborted and rolled back if duplicate-key errors occur. If `IGNORE` is specified, only one row is used of rows with duplicates on a unique key. The other conflicting rows are deleted. Incorrect values are truncated to the closest matching acceptable value.

Therefore, you can do:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE crm_ticketwatcher
  DROP PRIMARY KEY,
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (ticketid, employeeid);
```

Note however that which of the "duplicate" rows is preserved will be indeterminate.

If you want a more determinate outcome, or are using MySQL v5.7.4 and later (from which `IGNORE` has been removed), you can first perform a self-join with the multiple-table `DELETE` syntax:

```
DELETE c1
FROM   crm_ticketwatcher c1
  JOIN crm_ticketwatcher c2 USING (ticketid, employeeid)
WHERE  c1.contactid < c2.contactid -- or whatever logic you prefer
```

Comment: I got an error using that and found this on the MySQL documentation page

`As of MySQL 5.7.4, the IGNORE clause for ALTER TABLE is removed and its use produces an error.`

Comment: @GavinGassmann: And for the avoidance of doubt, you're using a version of MySQL ≥5.7.4?

Comment: Yes,I'll add the version to the OP as well.

Comment: Can you illustrate how that JOIN USING statement works? I'm having a tough time visualizing the composite key here. What would I replace the where statement with to preserve the last occuring/lowest row?

Comment: @GavinGassmann: `t1 JOIN t2 USING (a, b)` is shorthand for `t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.a = t2.a AND t1.b = t2.b` (with the additional effect of having only one of each such column in the resultset, such that they can be unambiguously referenced without table qualification).  What do you consider to be the "last occurring/lowest row" (bear in mind that, in SQL, tables don't have any innate ordering)?  As given above, my `DELETE` statement will preserve the record with the maximal `contactid` for each `(ticketid, employeeid)`—but delete all others.

Comment: I suppose I don't know what I mean by last occuring row. contactid is a fine way to handle it. Thank you!